# How to compare two csv files and get get the difference in an output file Java?

Tags: java, csv

Please I'm a newbie in java and I want to get get the difference between two csv files and map the correct values to the correct columns. The csv files have cvs contains. Here is my code.

```
package com.test.test;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException; 
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;  
import java.io.FileReader;  
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.*;


public class test3 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {
    compareFiles();
}


public static void compareFiles() {
    String line = ""; 
    String splitBy = ",";
    
    String filePath ="C:/Users/file1.csv";
    String filePath2 ="C:/Users/file2.csv";
    String outCSV = "C:/Users/Result.csv";

    try   
        {
     HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>(); 
     HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>(); 


        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));   
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)   //returns a Boolean value  
            {  
//              System.out.println("Line: " +line);
            String[] dataArray1 = line.split(splitBy);    // use comma as separator  
//              System.out.println("Id=" + dataArray1[0]);

                map1.put(dataArray1[0], dataArray1[1]+","+dataArray1[2]+","+dataArray1[3]+","+dataArray1[4]);
            }  
//              System.out.println("Size of Map : "+map1);


        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath2));   
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)   //returns a Boolean value  
            {  
//              System.out.println("Line: " +line);
            String[] dataArray2 = line.split(splitBy);    // use comma as separator  
//              System.out.println("Id=" + dataArray2[0] + ", Name=" + dataArray2[1]); 
            map2.put(dataArray2[0], dataArray2[1]); 
            }
                        
        FileWriter writer=new FileWriter(outCSV);


            for (String y : map1.keySet())
                {
            
                if (!map2.containsKey(y)) {
//                          System.out.println("Roll.no:" +y);  
                    
            String val=map1.get(y);
                System.out.println("The Value mapped to Key is:" +y+ " "+ val);
            writer.append(y);
            writer.append(val);
            writer.append("\n");
                System.out.println("Successful");
            writer.flush();
                }
                } 
                                    
                writer.close();
        }   
        catch (IOException e)   
        {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
        }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)  
                 {  
                 System.out.println("ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception occurs");
         e.printStackTrace();  
                } catch(NullPointerException e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
        
        }


}
```

}

file1.csv

id, name,address,productid,desc

1,  John,   John str,   3001,   shoe

2,  Jane    Jane drive, 3002,   shirt

3,  Mike,   Mike cres,  4001,   glasses

4,  Charlie,Charlie str,    5001,   hat

5,  James,  James drive,    6001,   wine

file2.csv

id, name

1,  John

2,  Jane

Comment: File diffs are not a simple thing.  You can easily test if two lines are different, but getting what those differences are is rather involved.

Comment: You'll need to give more details to receive effective help. What do you mean by 'difference'? By your use of an id field it's possible that your intent is to compare field values for matching ids. But it's pretty hard to tell from your question.

Comment: Try POI APIs it will help you to achieve your goal.

Comment: Am I right to consider that you don't want a character by character comparison, but a comparison on the level of rows, columns and field values?

Comment: I don't want a character by character comparison. I want to get my output based on matched ids and names. If both id and names in file2 exist in file1, that means they are matched, the output file will list the complete columns and rows. if there are any differences, I can ignore them or write it to another file.

Comment: I figured out a way to resolve this issue myself. thanks